# how to revert the execution policy to restricted after unrestricting

Tags: windows, python, flask

I had changed my execution policy in Windows powershell but would like to change it back to default
i.e unrestricted to restricted.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 3):

Just like how you ran...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

...to set it to unrestricted, you would simply run this to set it back to restricted:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Default` to ["\[set\] the default execution policy. Restricted for Windows clients or RemoteSigned for Windows servers."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6#parameters)

Comment: funnily enough, `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` did not work but `Set-ExecutionPolicy Default` did.